# Валидация XmlDocument, используя несклько Xsd схем

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Имеется XmlDocument, который необходимо проверить на соответствие 1 и более Xsd схеме.

Если схема одна и при валидации возникают ошибки, то обработка их происходит должным образом (ошибки отлавливаются). Если же схем более одной и проверка хотя бы одной проходит успешно, то ошибки валидации других почему-то не отлавливаются.

Примерно следующий код:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(Файл);

foreach (String name in НаборСхем))
{
    XmlSchema schema;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(Путь, name)))
    {
        schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
    }
    xml.Schemas.Add(schema);
}

xml.Validate((o, e) =>
{
    Exceptions.Add(e.Exception);
});
```

Почему так?